# Error PHP: Call to a member function set_charset() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando crear el registro de una web con PHP mediante PDO y MySQL + wamp y me salta el siguiente error al probarlo en localhost: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_charset() on null in C:\wamp64\www\SavingPaws\signup.php on line 15
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function set_charset() on null in C:\wamp64\www\SavingPaws\signup.php on line 15**
El código es el siguiente:
config.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Saving Paws</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        
        <?php
        
        try{
            //establecemos la conexión con la bd
        $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=saving_paws', 'root', '');
        echo 'Conexión OK'; //si se establece la conexion muestra el mensaje
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); //capturamos el error y lo mostramos
      
        } finally{
            $base=null;
        
        }
        ?>
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

*signup.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
  
 <table> 

<?php

require 'config.php';

$base->set_charset("utf8"); //Ponemoos la codificación en UTF-8
//Preparamos la consulta con la propiedad 'prepare', los parametros empezarán por ?
//importante almacenar la consulta en una nueva variable
$stmt = $base->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, apellidos, email, password,
          direccion, ciudad, telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $_POST['nombre'], $_POST['apellidos'], $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['ciudad'], $_POST['telefono'], $password);
        //i = tipo entero, d = float-decimal, s = cadena b = blob/datos binarios
        //bind_param = para pasar valores
$password = sha1($_POST['password2']); //damos una variable $password para poder usar como referencia
//encriptamos en SHA1
if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "sucess"; //imprimimos que el usuario es valido
} else {
    echo "failed";  //imprimimos que el usuario no es valido
}
```

Comment: tiene informacion parecida aqui : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574369/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-set-charset y https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: avísame si te ha servido :)

Comment: Te sobra el `finally`; creas la conexión y luego la tiras a la basura.

Comment: No, no me ha servido el primero @JavierG.Raya; @Sal he borrado el finally y me salta otro error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::set_charset() linea 15 (la misma que antes)

Comment: Acabo de darte una respuesta a este nuevo error que tienes ahora, que gracias a @Sal has solucionado la anterior.  Cuando la apliques verás que aparecerán nuevos errores, pero seran distintos a lo que has preguntado ahora, así que si no sabes resolverlos deberás abrir nuevas preguntas, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un poco de lio y malas practicas en tu código. Haz lo siguiente para superar el problema con el **set_charset**:

1. Debes eliminar todo el HTML de tu **config.php**, pues al hacer el `include` en el **signup.php** vas a duplicar las aperturas de los elementos `<html>`, `<head>` y `<body>`.

   Tal como su nombre indica `config.php` debería ser solo un archivo de configuración y no mostrar nunca nada directamente con el navegador, y para ello solo debe contener lo que hay ahora entre `<?php` y su cierre: `?>` y no hacer ni **echo** ni nada dentro de ellas. De hecho el cierre de `?>` tampoco es necesario si todo lo que contiene es código en PHP.

   Por lo tanto, tu **config.php** debería quedar así solamente:

```php
<?php
try {
   //establecemos la conexión con la bd
   $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saving_paws;charset=UTF8"', 'root', '');
} catch (Exception $e) {
   die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); //capturamos el error y lo mostramos
}
```

2. Fíjate que he quitado también el `echo 'Conexión OK';` porque como decía, no debe mostrar nada, y se sobreentiende que si no se muestra el `die()` que has puesto en el `catch` es que la conexión es correcta y no hace falta prodigarlo a los cuatro vientos (entiendo que lo estabas depurando, claro, pero con el **die()** es suficiente y ya lo dejas limpio).
3. Tal como ves arriba, he agregado `;charset=UTF8` en el parámetro [dsn](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-parameters) del PDO, así luego no te hace falta intentar lo del `$base->set_charset("utf8");` en tu archivo signup.php, que por cierto no te funciona porque no es una función de [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php), sino de [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset). Por lo tanto ya puedes borrar esa línea del **set_charset** y tu pregunta actual queda solventada.